# Creating screenshots on macOS Mojave without missing regions

Tags: macos, core-graphics, macos-mojave, cgimage, cgimageref

I have some code to create screenshots. On High Sierra it worked without issues. However, it does not work anymore properly since I run it on Mojave. Some parts are cut out. I use this API call:

```
CGImageRef screenshot = CGWindowListCreateImage
(CGRectInfinite, kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowImageDefault);
```

This option didn't work too `kCGWindowListOptionAll`. Attached are snippets of the screenshots with regions that are just white, i.e. missing. Note, I have intentionally removed the docker part below. I would actually just want to create plain full-screen snapshots.

Furthermore, even using the command line tool `screencapture` the the result is the same. Any ideas? Do I need to give certain permissions in "Security & Privacy"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No attachments!

Comment: @ankiiiiiii I just added them

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of `screencapture` failing like that? Are you by chance using the `-l <window id>` option?

Comment: Does `CGDisplayCreateImage()` capture those missing areas?

Comment: @Asmus I just did `screencapture shot.jpg`

Comment: @KenThomases Using this had the same effect. A side note: no monitor is attached to the Mac Mini. I do the screenshot via VNC.

Comment: If you take a "normal" screenshot (i.e. using cmd+shift+3), is it also producing white areas? What's in these regions (i.e. which app)?

Comment: SOLUTION: The issue was that no monitor was attached. In this case, macOS does not capture all regions/windows. As soon as I attached a monitor or KVM, everything worked fine. This seems to be bug.